# How did I break the fabric of time?

Tags: outer-wilds

First of all, I've already finished the game before, so I'm not worried about spoilers.

So, I revisited the Ash twin project, took the core out, realized that I didn't have enough time to do anything with it, so I put it back and waited for the sun to explode.  When it did, the core warped me to the beginning of the loop again.  I decided to go to Dark Bramble to find the Easter egg, but got eaten by an anglerfish.  I got informed that I had broken the fabric of time, and got the "You've met a terrible fate" achievement.  Then the credits started with Kazoo music.

I'm terribly confused, how did I end the loop?  The core is *still* in the ATP, so how did dying end the loop?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a bug. It's a cleverly hidden alternate ending, and one you've managed to stumble into without knowing why. Specifically, you've triggered the [Self ending](https://outerwilds.fandom.com/wiki/Endings). You sadly never met yourself, but that is not a requirement for the ending to trigger.

All you need to do to trigger the ending is to *cause* yourself to manifest as a duplicate, and then cause your duplicate to become a paradox on the next cycle, which is done by *not* repeating the same process that created them in the first place.

In short:

- The warphole you traveled through was only intended to send the signal and probe data back in time 22 minutes.
- You went through the hole. You **physically** travelled back in time. Normally, only your memories travel back to "younger" you.
- Because of this, you are now susceptible to a paradox. If you don't go through the warphole again, then you've effectively triggered the bootstrap paradox. You didn't go through the warphole, so you didn't travel back in time (this time).
- ...but the past has already been set in stone. You *did* arrive in the beginning of the loop after travelling from the end of the loop. Except... you didn't travel from the end of the loop (since an anglerfish ate you).
- Effectively, you came out of a portal, but you never went in it. This breaks the concept of spacetime, and it effectively crashes the universe.

Comment: That is seriously cool.  Thanks so much for the detailed answer, it's awesome how in depth the devs made that game.

Comment: "effectively crashes the universe." -> As I'm not familiar with the game, reading this crashed my brain

Comment: lol, if you like space, exploration,, and figuring out a really cool mystery just by scraps of information you gather which you have to put together, I would highly recommend it.  It's so good.

Comment: and yeah it sounds insane when you haven't played the game, lol